# jQuery UI nested connected sortables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have to use nested connected sortables with jQuery UI. That means that any sortable can be dropped in any other sortable. However, I am affected by this bug in jQuery UI: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8180. Briefly, dropping a sortable outside of a sortable throws an exception: "Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3".

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

While this hasn't been addressed, you can try adding a validation in _contactContainers() of the sortable widget before a value for the innermostContainer is assigned.

```
    for (var i = this.containers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){

        // never consider a container that's located within the item itself
        if($.contains(this.currentItem[0], this.containers[i].element[0]))
            continue;

        if(this._intersectsWith(this.containers[i].containerCache)) {

            // if we've already found a container and it's more "inner" than this, then continue
            if(innermostContainer && $.contains(this.containers[i].element[0], innermostContainer.element[0]))
                continue;

            if (this.currentItem[0] == this.containers[i].element[0]) {
                continue;
            }

            innermostContainer = this.containers[i];
            innermostIndex = i;

        } else {
            // container doesn't intersect. trigger "out" event if necessary
            if(this.containers[i].containerCache.over) {
                this.containers[i]._trigger("out", event, this._uiHash(this));
                this.containers[i].containerCache.over = 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

In the case of a sortable that can be connected and placed inside other sortables, the innermostContainer is determined as the current selected sortable. The placeholder is then appended inside it. When _clear() gets called on mouseStop, and "this.placeholder.before(this.currentItem)" gets called, the currentItem gets inserted before itself. This causes the HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3.

The simple checking, that if the currentItem is the container, disallows the placedholder to be appended to the currentItem.